# Key Value Pair of existing Object in C#

Tags: c#

How to get key value pair from object where any object has some value, I need to check if that key has some value itself like we do in javascript:

```
angular.forEach($scope.openedModel.Roaster, function (value, key) {
    if (value != null)
        for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            $scope.openedModel.roastersArray.push({ 'key': key, 'value': 1, 'picked': 0, 'users': {} });
        }
});
```

I have an Roster object in my code which I want the same like above in c#. Any help ?

Comment: What does the `Roster` object look like?

Comment: Show us your C# code. This can be easily done with linq.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Roster has all integer type properties. i.e. 8-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

So finally after did some trick in c#, I got a solution for my above problem:

```
var Roasters = typeof(RoastersModel).GetProperties()
                        .Select(prop => new { val = prop.GetValue(userPlayerPicks[0].DraftRoaster, null), Name = prop.Name })
                        .Where(val => val.val != null).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => Convert.ToInt32(x.val));
```

This returns me most similar object what we had in problem "$scope.openedModel.roastersArray".

Thanks to all contributors!!

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be -

```
Type type = obj.GetType(); //obj is your Rooster object
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + property.Name + ", Value: " + property.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```